# How can I force the Wordpress visual editor to preserve the line breaks after paragraphs?

Tags: css, editor, line-breaks

If I write and put a line break, it make the paragraph tags appropriately, but on this one page the line breaks aren't there:

http://jacksongariety.com/gundoglabs/jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The editor is doing fine to add `<p>` tag on line break. I think what you need is to add some css to add margin to `<p>` tag so you don't have to add additional or empty paragraph tags (which i see on your current page).

try something like this on your css:

```
.entry-content p{
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

That should give you a nice margin on top and bottom of the paragraph tag. Also you might want to add some margin on `<ul>` and `<li>` to get a good formatting.

Hope it helps. Let me know if you have any questions.